# Is passing socket.id from server to client possible security issue?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I'm using node.js with socket.io. Every socket connected to server has its own `socket.id`. I'm wondering if it is possible security issue if I pass `socket.id` from server to clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't believe that's a problem there aren't any known vulnerabilities to this, server-side socket.io is using ID to identify websocket connections just to "know" where to emit events and from where an event was emitted.